# Specifying variables in robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

My URL structure is set up in two parallels (both lead to the same place ):

- `www.example.com/subname`
- `www.example.com/123`

The trouble is is that, the spiders are crawling into things like:

- `www.example.com/subname/default_media_function`
- `www.example.com/subname/map_function`

Note that the name "subname" represents thousands of different pages on my site that all have that same function.

And they are throwing out errors because those links are strictly for JSON or AJAX purposes and not actual links. I would like to block them from accessing those pages, but how would I do that if the URL contains a variable?

Would this work in robots.txt?

```
Disallow: /map_function
```

Comment: This one surely works

    Disallow: /map_function/

Comment: Why did you write that as an answer? I'll give you the credit if it's true :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to do

```
Disallow: /subname/map_function
```

The robots will look for the *robots.txt* at root level. Also there they evaluate URLs left to right with no wildcards.

So, you will either need to make one location for all the map_function and exclude that, or exclude all locations.

Comment: Is it common for people to produce robot scripts dynamically? Because that var 'subname' represents thousands of different pages each with the same function. I'm just worried about making a huge robot.txt

Comment: I don't think you will need to worry too much about the size. Your best bet is to find a way to put all the elements into a single directory and then exclude the directory...

Disallow: /subname/restrict/

or something like that it will save you hassle on the robot.txt. However you can also do it dynamically how it's created doesn't matter to the bot.

Comment: so this is a mod_rewrite issue I take it. You might looking into using # to specify your parameters
jquery incorperates it. I think the bots wouldn't pay attention to anchors

Comment: Can I do what @Kaaviar said above? Just Disallow: /map_function/ or */map_function/  ?

Comment: * is a wildcard, this may work on google or larger engine but not smaller ones as it isn't part of the standard. The Search engines read the robot.txt stuff from left to right.

so /map_function/ is the same as http://www.domainname.com/map_function/

So that won't stop it. That's why if you can find a way to consolidate the map_function it's it's own directory or path that is the same across the subnames then you can prevent then from index it easier by simply restrict that one path.